# Who changed my GRUB theme to Debian?

Tags: 11.10, grub2

during these days I've upgraded from Natty to Oneiric and I've also installed the Gnome shell, just to give it a try.

I noticed this morning that GRUB theme is showing a Debian logo and I didn't request it!

Which package is known to set the GRUB theme to Debian one? I didn't install anything from external repositories so it should be an official Ubuntu package, but who exactly?

Do you know how to switch back to Ubuntu GRUB theme?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purge the package `desktop-base`:

```
sudo apt-get purge desktop-base
```

Then update the grub config file:

```
sudo update-grub
```